# IP Camera to Silverlight 4 Bus App

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

I'm needing to stream images from a network camera into a silverlight 4 business application. I have a MediaElement control on my page and am trying to set it's source property to where I believe the stream is, but not seeing anything in the MediaElement.

1) Camera is an Axis M1011 and I've tried streaming Mjpg/MPeg-4/H.264
2) Camera is on my network address 192.168.1.xxx
3) Setting source to all I can see in Axis documentation i.e. http://192.168.1.xxx/mjpeg/video.cgi"

Has anyone managed this and can you help me?

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this. I had to download AXIS video capture driver an use this as videocapturedevice in SL.....